# Read/Write on Raspberry Pi 3 Bluez C/C++

Tags: pi-3, linux, bluetooth, c, c++

Once I'm connected to a bluetooth device I try to read and write a request by handle or uuid (I tried both) with no success.

I'm using this library [gattlib-master](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib) which works for the examples of ble_scan and discover with little changes.

The problem is that the example [read_write](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib/blob/master/examples/read_write/read_write.c), never fills the buffer used in both functions  `gattlib_read_char_by_uuid(connection, &g_uuid, buffer, sizeof(buffer));` and `gattlib_write_char_by_handle(connection, handle, buffer, sizeof(buffer));`

Any idea of were could the problem be? If not, can anyone tell me where could I find read/write examples with Bluez for Linux in C/C++?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to post a code sample reproducing the issue if you want help with your code. You say you made "little changes" to the library, do you expect people to guess what those changes are?

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of [gattlib](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib). I have sign-in to try to help you with your issue.
Unfortunately, my reputation is not high enough to leave a comment to your initial message. You can also leave your issue on [Github](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib/issues/new), maybe someone will have the same issue as you.

Feel free to contribute to Gattlib. I will be happy to review your changes and integrate them back to the repository.

To come back on your issue, can you connect to your BLE device with `gatttool` and read the characteristic. It would be something like that?

`gatttool -b <your-ble-address> -I
connect
char-read-uuid <uuid-of-your-characteristic>`

Comment: Yes I am able to do it, but when I compile the read/write functions they do not work correctly as the buffer where the information should be written is always empty. However, the scan function works perfectly. @Olivier